# Apache StreamPipes - Kafka topic data reading time out

Tags: apache-kafka, timeout, streampipes

i have the problem with loading the data from Kafka topic to Apache StreamPipes adapter.

I'm using Kafka 3.5.0 and Apache StreamPipes 0.93 (but the same problem occurs on 0.92), i have the default topic named connect-configs with single JSON object, and i'm trying to create new adapter for it. Topic is visible on configuration screen, i can move to the next step, but when it's starting to load data from topic, I'm receiving such an error

[Apache StreamPipes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYNnZ.png)

The topic for sure has data, it is single JSON object with 3 fields so it's not even big enough to cause time out issues. Apache Streampipes and Kafka works on the same ubuntu VM. Any ideas what is wrong with that?

I also tried to use debezium topics from SQL Server (data from few records), and it was the same scenario.